# Android OkHttp library: GET Request - Exception EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=

Tags: java, android, http, get, okhttp

I'm using in my app OkHttp library (http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and in one simple GET request I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
   at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:201)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
   ...

unexpected end of stream on Connection{th.it-bedna.cz:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=85.118.128.42 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
```

Other Get requests to the same address works OK. And if I type this request to the Chrome it works also OK. Do you know where is a problem?

Thanks for any advice.

Edit: code of the GET

```
public Call doGetRequest(String url, Callback callback) {
    com.squareup.okhttp.Request request = new com.squareup.okhttp.Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(callback);
    return call;
}
```

Using:

```
void getData()
{
    String url = "http://th.it-bedna.cz/api/v2/event/1/user?i=8";
    Singleton.getInstance().doGetRequest(url, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            Log.i("CDT", "onFailure: " + e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is your emulator configured with any proxy? For I'm getting this error only when enabled the proxy otherwise working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is `th.it-bedna.cz` as in your logcat info, you can try the following code:

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        // GET request
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://th.it-bedna.cz")
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, response.body().string());
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, response.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm using similar code and it does not work. Url is http://th.it-bedna.cz/api/v2/event/1/user?i=8 Can you try it with this url?

Comment: Working with `http://th.it-bedna.cz/api/v2/event/1/user`, the logcat `2-04 16:17:11.465 1544-1558/com.example.asyncokhttp W/OkHttp: {"status":1}
12-04 16:17:11.465 1544-1558/com.example.asyncokhttp I/OkHttp: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://th.it-bedna.cz/api/v2/event/1/user}`

Comment: Ah, I have justed test with `http://th.it-bedna.cz/api/v2/event/1/user?i=8` in my Android app, it works with the same logcat above

Comment: Oh...it's weird. I will have to look at it more. Do you have some tip where can be a problem?

Comment: Not yet, pls post more code where caused that exception.

Comment: I suggest you use my code, it's working with your url (`http://th.it-bedna.cz/api/v2/event/1/user?i=8`)

Comment: Have you set INTERNET permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes, I have INTERNET permission. I don't know where can be a problem. I tried a lot of different "solutions".

Comment: And you added to the Gradle dependecies only "compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0' "?

Comment: Yes, `dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
}` have you tried in another device/emulator with different API yet? Pls post your full project to google drive/onedrive... so that I can check more

Comment: OkHttpClient.SetRetryOnConnectionFailure(true);

Source: The issue raised on Github and this answer: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1517#issuecomment-144069139

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with **OkHttpClient** and **HttpURLConnection**.
My android emulator was configured to use proxy, but my proxy wasn't accepting connections.

Doesn't mater if you use proxy or not if destination host refuses connection you will get that exception.